# Does progress bar slows down application?

Tags: android

When I have a progress bar, it takes much longer for my application to start in comparison to starting up without a progress bar. Is it possible or maybe it is just a vision effect?

Comment: Measure it and get your own (best) answer. You may use `currentTimeMillies()` to measure.

Comment: This could be the reason why you are having this issue. Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40336227/7093489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose (and also noticed) that the creation and modification of a progress bar takes some time. The time overhead is less important on long running operations but it is noticeable on short operations (few seconds).

I however prefer waiting 5 seconds with progress bar instead of 3 seconds without (and just the feeling that nothing happens or system hangs).

Answer (score 0):

No progress bar does not effects your pressing even it is used for the long running operations if your progress bar is taking more time then you need to look at logCAT in ddms perspective to identify real problem.