# Android ProgressBar makes app to work slower

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I am making to show progressbar on postexecute and to be not visible in postExecute,  and it works, but makes the app to work very slow, what is the reason is there any simple way to make it work normal(not slowly)?
This is my code:

```
bar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);     
getInfo extends AsyncTask<void, void, void>{   
    protected void onPreExecute() {   
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }   
    protected void doInBackground(String... params)                                                  
                  do smth}  
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean results) {
              bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: from where do you invoke asynctask

Comment: post the code where you invoke asynctask by editing your post.

Comment: Would it start working at a normal speed if I put the code:"bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);" where I invoke asynctask, and leave the code:"bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);" in onPostExecute?   Thank you again :)

Comment: i asked you to post the code here on stackoverflow by editing your post so that either me or someone will be able to help

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a custom progress bar and are you showing the progress bar at the initial screen of your application?

If you are using a custom progress bar then it might take some time to load during the initial startup of your app. I had a similar issue and the issue was due to the android:type="sweep" in the custom progress bar. EG: below

```
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#000001"
            android:centerColor="#ffffff"
            android:centerY="0.5"
            android:type="sweep"/>
    </shape>
```

Not sure why the type="sweep" could cause the issue but, after removing it, the application seemed to start up pretty quick